# Function of a random variable is a random variable

Tags: random-variables, elementary-probability

Consider the following two statements

[Statement 1](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_3_functions_continuous_var.php)

> If $X$ is a continuous random variable and $Y=g(X)$ is a **function** of
> $X$, then $Y$ itself is a random variable.

[Statement 2](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/StatInference/notes/lecture5.pdf)

> A random variable is a function from a sample space S into the **real
> numbers**.

From statement 2 it is clear that a random variable should be a real valued function.

Then how can **any** function of a random variable can be another random variable as per statement 1? Where my interpretation is going wrong?

Comment: I see Statement 1 in the book but it looks as though the author has no interest in Mathematical rigor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement 1 is wrong. If $X$ is a random variable and $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a **measurable function** then $g(X)$ is a random variable. However, if $X$ is a discrete random variable then any function of $X$ is a random variable.

Comment: Can you cite some source proving this statement? I'd be interested :)

Comment: @DiegoStucchi Just note that $(g(X))^{-1} (E)=X^{-1}(g^{-1}(E)$ for any Borel set $E$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, how can it accept a function as argument as in $g(X)$? I think it should rather be $g\circ X$.

Answer (score 2):

Without any more context, statement 1 is completely wrong. Let gives context. Statement 2 doesn't really have sense as well. I denote $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ the Borel set of $\mathbb R$

- Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and let $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable if $X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal F$ for all $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.
- Let $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a Borel function (i.e. $g^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ for all $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$). Then $g(X)$ is indeed a r.v. since $$(g\circ X)^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}\left(\underbrace{g^{-1}(B)}_{\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)}\right)\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R),$$
  which is completely independent of continuity of $X$ that have no sense in context of probability (there is no topology on $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. May by by $X$ continuous you mean the density function is continuous, but still, no need this property to have $g(X)$ a r.v.

Comment: Can you cite some source for this statement?

Comment: A sorce for waht ? @DiegoStucchi

Comment: For the proposition you just wrote here. When I say "source", I mean any kind of Maths book or paper or anything like that :)

Comment: Source for which result ? these are definitions or direct consequence from definitions... that's why I don't understand for which result you want a source. @DiegoStucchi

Answer (score 1):

$X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. to each $\omega$ you pair some real number $X(\omega)$.

Then, $Y$ given by $g(X)$ should be interpreted as pairing $g(X(\omega))$ to each $\omega$.

In other words $Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and is just $g \circ X$.